# C - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I keep getting a Segmentation Fault error when I run the program with a txt files with 5 numbers. First number is 5 (size of array) and then 0 1 2 3 4 It compiles just fine when I gcc -c *.c.

Main file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "my.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 char* file = argv[1];
 int n;
 int* a;
 int i,j;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(file, "r"); // open file

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &n); //scans for the first value for n 

    a = calloc(n, sizeof (int));
    int num;

    for (i =0; i<n - 1; i++) //stores and reads value 
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &num);
        a[i] = num;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    int* b;
    b = f(a, n);
    displayValue(b);

 return 0;
}
```

Functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "my.h"
int* f(int* a, int n)
{

    //odd-even sort
    int h,j, c;
    for ( h = 0; h < n - 1; h++)
    {
        if(a[h]%2==0)
        {
        if (a[h] > a[h + 1])
            {
                int temp = a[h];
                a[h] = a[h +1];
                a[h + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
        {
            if(a[j]%2!=0)
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1])
            {
                int temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j +1];
                a[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
return a;
}

void displayValue(int* b)
    {
    int index = 0;
        while (0 == 0)
        {
            printf("Enter the index: ");
            scanf("%d", &index);
            if (index == -1)
                exit(0);
            else
                printf("%s", &b[index]);
        }
    }
```

Header

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
int* my(int* a, int n);
void displayValue(int* b);
```

Comment: Should we just *guess* what the function `my()` looks like?

Comment: Where exactly does it crash? Where is the definition of `my` function? Why did you insert declaration `void displayValue(int* b);` into the body of `main`? (Yet you never call `displayValue` anywhere.) Why did you post a (quite large) definition of function `f`, which is not called anywhere?

Comment: Typo - I actually have my as f in my mode not sure where that came from.

Comment: You never check whether `calloc` or `fopen` fail. or if `file == NULL` or if `argc < 2`

Comment: Yea I don't know why I re-declaring that method displayValue in main again. I'm correcting that now.

Comment: @isma2012: Well, post real code. Nobody wants to decode your substitution cipher "`f` is actually `my`" and so on.

Comment: Thanks for feedback everyone. I made a few edits and when I call displayValue now it gives me an error saying "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: @MattMcNabb yea error handling is not required yet for the project.

Comment: @isma2012 any of those errors could cause your segmentation fault

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'll wrap it up to see

Comment: @isma2012: The error/warning is probably caused by the fact that you changed the function name from `my` to `f` in `main`, but never corrected the header file, which still declares `my`. The previous warning message probably told you that `f` is undeclared.

Comment: `printf("%s", &b[index]);` wrong.

Comment: should be `printf("%d\n", b[index]);`

Comment: and it is read only (n-1) number of int instead of the n as logic error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is dangerous. Anything that can go wrong will go wrong.

Always check the return values of function calls, and handle possible failures.

Each of the standard library function calls has a `man` page (if you have trouble finding it, use `man -a <function>`). The `man` pages document the possible return values and their meanings. `man` is your fried, get used to studying it; it is a valuable resource.

Beware of conditions that result in "undefined behavior".

Comment: +1. And compile with `-Wall`. Catches lots of problems up front.